# Change Exception Permissions

Tags: reports, permissions, exception

Magento is writing exceptions to var/reports with 0640 permissions, owned by "nobody". My user can't access them. How can I change this?

Comment: I **chmod** this file and access it

Comment: My user has no root access. How do I change Magento to write report files with proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply permission to **var**

Run command with root user : `chmod -R 777 var`